# JAXB: How to list identical child elements having different tags names

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML in following format:

```
<servers>
      <server_1>
          <name>S1</name>
          <user>User1</user>
          <pass>pass1</pass>
      </server_1>
      <server_2>
          <name>S2</name>
          <user>User2</user>
          <pass>pass2</pass>
      </server_2>
      <server_3>
          <name>S3</name>
          <user>User3</user>
          <pass>pass3</pass>
      </server_3>
</servers>
```

There can be multiple child elements under servers. And I am having trouble figuring out how to parse these using JAXB unmarshel. If the child would have identical name I could have just unmarshelled them into a list.

I also looked at @XMLAnyElement annotation which would allow me to have these elements into a list but I was facing some type cast issues since doing that gives ElementNSImpl and then I'd have to convert it to a simple Server entry class. Is that the only way to process such case?

Can't I use regex in @XMLElement's name field to populate such entries ignoring the different tags (server_1 , server_2 etc) or any other way to disregard the different child element tags.

I was using this guide to understand XMLAnyElement behavior:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html but this is not really for my kind of use case.

Another approach I was thinking is of modifying the parent xml itself and replacing server_X type tags with server using Java FileReaders before unmarshling the XML file.

I will appreciate help or pointing me in right direction.

Edit: I see that following code works-

```
    ..
    ..
     @XmlAnyElement
        public List<ElementNSImpl> getServer() {
            return server;
        }
    ..
    ..
public void printElem() {
        if(server!=null) {
            for(ElementNSImpl serverEntry :server) {
                NodeList nodeList= ftpEntry.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("length:"+nodeList.getLength());
                for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength()-1;i++)
                    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName()+" :"+nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
```

But java gives warning message on using ElementNSImpl directly:

```
Access restriction: The type 'ElementNSImpl' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\rt.jar')
```

So I am not sure if it is okay to use ElementNSImpl like this.

Comment: How many possible different names are there? Is it possible to enumerate them? If yes, then `@XmlElementRef` is a way to go.

Comment: @lexicore do you mean Tag Names? They will be of format server_[index]. Where index will be a decimal from 1-50. And there can be as many as 50 child elements. And these index after the underscores will be in linear continuous order